# How are errors typically preserved in an MVC framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

When submitting a form and errors are detected the user is generally directed back to the same form with preserved input and highlighted errors. However, in order to avoid the possibility of receiving an error message as follows:

[image: Form re-submission]

The form is redirected using `header('Location:');` so that the "action" of the form isn't saved in the browsers history.

Since the redirection creates a new request, how are errors typically preserved from one request to the next? I'm inclined to use `$_SESSION`, but from what I gather using sessions for error handling is frowned upon.

I appreciate any insight into this matter.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with using $_SESSION there, I do that sometimes. Just write the same $_SESSION['error_string'] that would for every error and overwrite it if you get another. It's just one variable, and as long as its not sensitive information its nbd.

Answer (score 2):

in an MVC framework, you have access to the request variables and deliver the intended page both in the same request, with a redirect involved you would use sessions or query vars in the url.

Comment: the query var is a good idea, you could have a file that maps an id to an error message, then just pass the error message ID's in the url when they are redirected

Answer (score 1):

Errors should not be anything, that is handled by any wide-range framework. Instead it should be part of the application itself.

The generation and both permanent and temporary storage of errors should be handles by model layers, while the presentation of said errors is strictly a responsibility of view instances. And, since the actual parts of MVC are not governed by framework, this makes the dealing with errors outside the purview of framework.